# Compiling Modular Boost 1.55.0 with Submodule Application

Tags: c++, git, boost, g++, boost-asio

I've cloned the modulare boost git repository (liked described here: [description](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/TryModBoost), but not only headers) onto my windows machine (Windows 7 64 bit, using MinGW g++ 4.4.1 but also tried version 4.8.1). I used the following commands:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git clone --recursive git@github.com:boostorg/boost.git modular-boost > clone.log
cd modular-boost
```

Before building it, i added the submodule [boost.application](https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application) into libs/application:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application.git libs/application
```

After inserting the submodule, building it:

```
.\bootstrap gcc
.\b2 --layout=tagged link=shared variant=debug threading=multi toolset=gcc
```

1. Some libraries didn't compile (like boost log). Did I miss here something?
2. I tried to work with the existing compiled libraries (mainly I am using System, Thread, Prg_Exec_Monitor, Unit Tests and Program Options), but I always get an error in `boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp`:

   ```
   error: 'SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT' was not declared in this scope
   ```

   Here is an example code, where this error occurs:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <boost/application.hpp>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       cout << "SO_Question_Test" << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to `0x0601` (Windows 7).

Comment: Is this supported by the library Boost Application? I would be surprised if it was. Also, try explicitly `.\b2 headers` (I'm not sure whether this is implicit)

Comment: what support do you mean? `_WIN32_WINNT`-version? I've tried that but that changed nothing. I've also tried to replace the include of application with boost asio but that changed nothing. The error stil occurs.

Comment: I meant support to use Boost Application as a submodule in modular boost

Comment: boost.applications links to [TryModBoost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/TryModBoost) for its build instructions. I followed that and thought I add the application library as a submodule like all other libraries are. Do you know another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added partial support for MinGW. Please download the last version again (0.4.9) and check this:

Build Boost.Application on MinGW steps:

1) Download MinGW

2) Install it, and add 'C:/MinGW/bin' to your PATH.

3) Install gcc
   -> open a console window and type:

> mingw-get install gcc

4) Build Boost for MinGW

From your boost_X_XX_X directory, go to

.\tools\build\v2

in my case : C:\boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2

and type:

> bootstrap.bat mingw
>
> cd C:\boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2
>
> bootstrap.bat mingw

Return to your boost_X_XX_X directory and type:

> bjam toolset=gcc

5) Install Boost.TypeIndex 4.0 (for boost < 1.56)

If you are using boost < 1.56 you need install Boost.TypeIndex 4.0

5.1) Download it

5.2) Copy content of: c:\type_index\include\boost\ to C:\boost_1_54_0\boost\

6) Install  Boost.Application 0.4.9

6.1) Download it

6.2) Copy content of: c:\application\include\boost\ to C:\boost_1_54_0\boost\

7) Install, compile and run "tests" **

7.1) Create a new folder called "application" inside C:\boost_1_54_0\libs\

7.2) Copy folder: c:\application\test to C:\boost_1_54_0\libs\appliacation

c:\application*

7.3) Compile and run:

> cd C:\boost_1_54_0\libs\application\test
>
> bjam toolset=gcc define=BOOST_APPLICATION_FEATURE_NS_SELECT_BOOST

Use BOOST_APPLICATION_FEATURE_NS_SELECT_BOOST to force use of boost (boost::shared_ptr, boost::unordered_map and so on) as default

8) Install, compile and run "example"

8.1) Create a new folder called "application" inside C:\boost_1_54_0\libs\

8.2) Copy folder: c:\application\example to C:\boost_1_54_0\libs\application

8.3) Compile and run:

> cd C:\boost_1_54_0\libs\application\example
>
> bjam toolset=gcc

The examples defines 'BOOST_APPLICATION_FEATURE_NS_SELECT_BOOST' direct on code

[*] c:\application = your download from github

[**] The "bjam" needs to be available in the system

Article: https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application/wiki/Boost.Application-on-MinGW

Letme know if work!

Comment: With version 4.8.1 (32-bit MinGW) I was never able to build my application, so I tried out some other versions. I finaly get it working with mingw 64 bit (gcc version 4.9.0). Thank you for this nice answer! Works fine!